# Fancy header line with section name

Tags: header-footer, section-titles

I have a question about the header of a latex document (`article` class). I want to create a header like

**Section 1. {section name}**

on the left of my header line, but when I use `\leftmark` command, it returns error. I tried to use `\rightmark` command but the header just have the title of the subsection. Could some one help me to solve this problem? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the error message, so I cannot say, why `\leftmark` does not work in your code. As usual a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) would have been useful, to see what you've tried and why it does not work.

Usually it does work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhead[L]{\bfseries\leftmark}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[C]{}
\renewcommand*{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand*{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{Section~\thesection.~#1}{}}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

But as an alternative, using `scrlayer-scrpage` you don't need it in this case:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[automark,markcase=used]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\renewcommand*{\sectionmarkformat}{Section~\thesection.~}% Format of the number
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\bfseries}% Don't use slant, but bold

\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

In other cases, you could simply use `\headmark` with `scrlayer-scrpage`.

Both examples with the same result:

[image: result using \leftmark]

With `fancyhdr` also `\rightmark` could be correct:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhead[L]{\bfseries\rightmark}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[C]{}
\renewcommand*{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand*{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{Section~\thesection.~#1}}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Whether `\leftmark` or `\rightmark` should be used, depends on the expected result with more than one `\section` on the same page.

Comment: Your codes work for me. Thank you so much!